# Sequence of letters ABCD, pigeon hole?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Show that in every sequence $(a_1 , a_2 , \ldots, a_{100})$ of the letters $A,B,C,D,$ there are two indices $1 \leq i < j < 98$ such that $(a_i,a_{i+1},a_{i+2}) = (a_j,a_{j+1},a_{j+2})$.

I don’t really even understand what this is asking or what principles I should be using.

Comment: You are trying to prove there exists a sequence of three letters which appears twice in the sequence. For example, if the sequence started `ABACCDADBACA...`, then `BAC` appears twice in that sequence. There are $4\times 4\times 4$ possible three letter subsequences, and there are $98$ subsequences in your sequence, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asked to prove that in any such sequence there are two equal subsequences of length 3.

The technique you should use is [pigeongole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

First, how many different sequenced of length $3$ do exist if every element has $4$ options ($A, B, C, D$)? 
Next, how many sub-sequences of length 3 does you sequence contain? (Clearly it is $98$) 
You are only left to divide second value by first one and make a conclusion from pigeongole principle.